# PHP: How to get specific word from string

Tags: php, arrays, string

This is my string:

```
$string="VARHELLO=helloVARWELCOME=123qwa";
```

I want to get 'hello' and '123qwa' from string.

My pseudo code is.

```
if /^VARHELLO/ exist
    get hello(or whatever comes after VARHELLO and before VARWELCOME)
if /^VARWELCOME/ exist
    get 123qwa(or whatever comes after VARWELCOME)
```

**Note**: values from 'VARHELLO' and 'VARWELCOME' are dynamic, so 'VARHELLO' could be 'H3Ll0' or VARWELCOME could be 'W3l60m3'.

```
Example: 
$string="VARHELLO=H3Ll0VARWELCOME=W3l60m3";
```

Comment: Look at PHP's [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function

Comment: why dont you split with a separator like "VARHELLO=H3Ll0&VARWELCOME=W3l60m3" then explode into an array?

Comment: Ok what If the separator is space?

Comment: @bub - the separator is the VAR part.

Comment: I already tried the separator '&' and used 'parse_str()', and it works but this is the given problem.

Comment: See the solution of @Jessica below

Comment: @KuhaCoAkawntMo What about case "VARHELLO=VARWELCOMEVARWELCOME=foo" ? If the string _always_ has two keys better approach would be to use preg_match like in Mubin-Khalid's answer

Answer (score 4):

Here is some code that will parse this string out for you into a more usable array.

```
<?php
$string="VARHELLO=helloVARWELCOME=123qwa";
$parsed = [];
$parts = explode('VAR', $string);

foreach($parts AS $part){
   if(strlen($part)){
       $subParts = explode('=', $part);
       $parsed[$subParts[0]] = $subParts[1];
   }

}

var_dump($parsed);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["HELLO"]=>
  string(5) "hello"
  ["WELCOME"]=>
  string(6) "123qwa"
}
```

Or, an alternative using `parse_str` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
<?php
$string="VARHELLO=helloVARWELCOME=123qwa";
$string = str_replace('VAR', '&', $string);

var_dump($string);
parse_str($string);

var_dump($HELLO);
var_dump($WELCOME);
```

Output:

```
string(27) "&HELLO=hello&WELCOME=123qwa"
string(5) "hello"
string(6) "123qwa"
```

Comment: Thanks. You save my time.

Comment: I would recommend against using parse_str() as it pollutes scope, and could introduce security issues: `"VAR&_GET=..."`

Answer (score 2):

Jessica's answer is perfect, but if you want to get it using `preg_match`

```
$string="VARHELLO=helloVARWELCOME=123qwa";

preg_match('/VARHELLO=(.*?)VARWELCOME=(.*)/is', $string, $m);

var_dump($m);
```

your results will be `$m[1]` and `$m[2]`

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
    string(31) "VARHELLO=helloVARWELCOME=123qwa"
  [1]=>
    string(5) "hello"
  [2]=>
    string(6) "123qwa"
```

}